# JavaScript RegEx to mimic eval

Tags: javascript, regex, string, eval

How would be the RegEx to make the string

```
'{"a":"st", "b":"EvalMe(nd)", "c":"th"}'
```

become

```
'{"a":"st", "b":nd, "c":"th"}'
```

?

Comment: its no regexp but if its always this pattern, than i would you .replace()

Comment: 1) what have you tried? 2) Why use regex? Other than the fact that you're breaking the JSON syntax, is there a reason you can't just parse and manipulate the object directly?

Comment: The json was just an example to ilustrate what I need, the real string will be a full Javascript code loaded via Ajax. The "nd" thing need to be a variable, because if I let the code be parsed it will just break, because it is expecting the nd to be an object, not a string.
I already know I need to use replace with a regex, but I can't figure out the regex. I'm trying all the day long, but regex just fly over my head. :)

Comment: This, for example:
str.replace(/"EvalMe\\(/g,"").replace(/\\)"/g,"");

do what I need, but it would be best to be in 1 regex, because the ')"' need to be matched only when it is part of a 'EvalMe('.

Comment: Too lazy to look it up right now, but what you need is a regEx with a capture group. You'll want to look for "EvalMe(" then a capture group of some characters which are *not* ")" and then a single ")". The matched capture group is the substring you're looking for. See for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple find and replace is all you need
find:  `/"EvalMe\(([^()]*)\)"/`
replace: `\1` or `$1`

Comment: Thank you! It did the trick.
str.replace(/"EvalMe\(([^()]*)\)"/g, "$1")

Comment: Update:
str.replace(/[",']EvalMe(([^()]*))[",']/g, "$1")

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `json`. So first using `json library`(not sure how in Javascript) parse this value first `"b":"EvalMe(nd)"` from the `json`.

Then from there do a regex replace like below way and then update your `json`.

```
output = "EvalMe(nd)".replace(/.*\((.*?)\).*/, "$1");
                                   ^^^^^ picking of nd is here
```

Here using regex it is capturing the `nd` in group `$1` and replace everything with empty, and keeping the group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the json is just to simplificate an example. I need it to replace in the full string, like the example I gave in the comment above.